# VBA for date filter returning blank

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

When I run the below macro all rows are hidden even though when I click into the filter and reapply (I don't change the text just press enter). I have also made sure that the data is formatted appropriately. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 Sub Dates()
    '
    ' Dates Macro
    '
    Dim todaysdate As Date
    Dim ITTrecieved As Date
    Dim greaterthan
    greaterthan = ">="
    todaysdate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    todaysdate = CDbl(todaysdate)

    ITTrecieved = DateSerial(Year(todaysdate), Month(todaysdate) - 2, Day(todaysdate))
    ITTrecieved = CDbl(ITTrecieved)


'
        ActiveSheet.Range("F3").AutoFilter Field:=5, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & ITTrecieved, Operator:=xlFilterValues

        ActiveSheet.Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & todaysdate, Operator:=xlFilterValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Side note... why are you `CDbl`ing a date?

Comment: Are you applying a filter to both column F and H ?

Comment: On the Cdbl thing I took that from  adifferent stack that seemed to have a similar issue. Regarding the filter, yes to both Columns F and H and the table starts in column B.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FilterDates()
'
    Dim todaysdate As Date
    Dim ITTrecieved As Date

    todaysdate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    todaysdate = CDbl(todaysdate)

    ITTrecieved = DateSerial(Year(todaysdate), Month(todaysdate) - 2, Day(todaysdate))
    ITTrecieved = CDbl(ITTrecieved)


    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=">=" & ITTrecieved, Operator:=xlAnd
.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & todaysdate, Operator:=xlAnd
End With

End Sub
```

Hey there, I think I am just not understanding what you would like to see. What I took it as that you are trying to filter data using two different filters from two different columns. Your code seems to do that, but if you are seeing different results then that means I completely misunderstood.

[Before Macro Filter Ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO8Ai.png)

[After Macro Filter Ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57I9K.png)

Comment: It seems like all the versions (including yours) on this thread seems to be working fine. Only thing I can think of, I know you said the data is formatted correctly, is that the spreadsheet data is different from what we are thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Sub Dates()

    Dim today As Double, ITTrecieved As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    today = Date
    ITTrecieved = DateAdd("m", -2, today)

    ws.Range("F3").AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & ITTrecieved, Operator:=xlAnd

    ws.Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & today, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: This resulted in a filter being applied to column D

Comment: @alistair updated answer because filter is on a table header

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help I worked out what the error was. I was Cdbling the today filter to early so that was messing with the ITTReceived variable therefore being affected. The below worked:

```
Sub Dates()
```

'    Dim todaysdate As Date
'    Dim ITTrecieved As Date

todaysdate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

```
ITTrecieved = DateSerial(Year(todaysdate), Month(todaysdate) - 2, Day(todaysdate))
ITTrecieved = CDbl(ITTrecieved)
todaysdate = CDbl(Date)
```

'    ActiveSheet.Range("F3").AutoFilter Field:=5, _
'        Criteria1:=">=" & ITTrecieved, Operator:=xlFilterValues

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F3").AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=">" & ITTrecieved, Operator:=xlOr
```

'    ActiveSheet.Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
'        Criteria1:=">=" & todaysdate, Operator:=xlFilterValues

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">" & todaysdate, Operator:=xlOr
```

End Sub